# codeigniter and responsive design

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Please i have a problem with making responsive design using foundation.zurb and codeigniter framework as i created a web app with foundation.zurb and php codeigniter framework and after finish i chocked with the preview as the web app appears without any responsive of being the device is mobile or not.

here is my responsive code :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 xlarge-6 columns text-center">
        <div class="panel callout radius text-center">
          <!---- my contents goes here ----->
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the css files working correctly

so how i can solve this ??

Comment: This has nothing to do with CodeIgniter. I can't help you with Foundation framework, but double check if the files are being executed through console.

Comment: way too many things can be at play here. JS libraries, CSS not loading properly, path issues, the list goes on. What you posted, isn't enough to go on. What you posted, is "bootstrap" syntax code.

Comment: Can you show us your `<meta>` code too? Normally, it's a problem with the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

There is no behaviour in your file, you have a single incomplete row, so no responsive code is actually applied, first off, you just need to select your maximum size and no need to go... To explain better

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        <div class="panel callout radius text-center">
            <!-- Your Content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        <div class="panel callout radius text-center">
            <!-- Your Content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now we have two panels, that from medium size (about 700px wide) onwards will look as two columns, but under that width, will collapse one above another, If this is not working, your CSS is likely not working, missing the

```
<meta name="viewport" value="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

That goes on the header